# how to hide & toggle through sections in one HTML file

Tags: jquery, html, css

The code looks like this

```
<section id="vehicle-year" class="active">
  <ul class="pager">
    <a href="#vehicle-make">Car production year goes here</a>
  </ul> 
</section>

<section id="vehicle-make">
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="previous "><a href="#vehicle-year" ><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Back</a>
   </li>
   <a href="#vehicle-type"> Car make goes here</a>
       </ul>
</section>

<section id="vehicle-type">
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="previous "><a href="#vehicle-make" ><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Back</a>
    </li>
     <a href="#vehicle-type"> Car type goes here</a>
   </ul>
 </section>
```

I want to start with the first section displaying only, you should be able to click on the < a > tag in the first section to get to the second section & the same from the second to third. I am having issues trying to hide the sections that are not active.

What should be the next steps here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea. Modify as desired.

```js
var prev, here, next;
$('a').click(function(){
    here = '#' + $(this).closest('section').attr('id');
    next = $(this).attr('href');
    $(here).removeClass('active');
    $(next).addClass('active');
});
$('.previous').click(function(){
   prev = '#' + $(this).closest('section').attr('id');
   $(prev).removeClass('active');
   here = prev;
});
```

```css
section{display:none;}
.active{display:block !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="vehicle-year" class="active">
  <ul class="pager">
    <a href="#vehicle-make">Car production year goes here</a>
  </ul> 
</section>

<section id="vehicle-make">
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="previous "><a href="#vehicle-year" ><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Back</a>
    </li>
    <a href="#vehicle-type"> Car make goes here</a>
  </ul>
</section>

    <section id="vehicle-type">
      <ul class="pager">
        <li class="previous "><a href="#vehicle-make" ><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Back</a>
        </li>
         <a href="#vehicle-type"> Car type goes here</a>
       </ul>
     </section>
```

Comment: @StackOverflow You're welcome. Please select a correct answer when ready to close the question. As we say in French, *bon chance*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need use click functions in Jquery and change css property display like that:

```js
$("#first").click(function(){

  $("section").css("display","none");
  $("#vehicle-make").css("display","block");

});

$("#second").click(function(){

  $("section").css("display","none");
  $("#vehicle-type").css("display","block");

});

$("#third").click(function(){

  $("section").css("display","none");
  $("#vehicle-make").css("display","block");

});
```

```css
section {
  display:none;
  }

.active{
  display:block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="vehicle-year" class="active">
  <ul class="pager">
    <a href="#" id="first">Car production year goes here</a>
  </ul> 
</section>

<section id="vehicle-make">
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="previous "><a href="#vehicle-year" ><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Back</a>
   </li>
   <a href="#" id="second"> Car make goes here</a>
       </ul>
</section>

<section id="vehicle-type">
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="previous "><a href="#vehicle-make" ><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Back</a>
    </li>
     <a href="#" id="third"> Car type goes here</a>
   </ul>
 </section>
```